# Debian - All processes have low memory usage yet no more free RAM

Tags: memory, debian, ram

According to `free` my RAM is completely full:

```
:~# free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048       2048          0          0          0       1957
-/+ buffers/cache:         90       1957
Swap:         2048          0       2048
```

But `ps aux` only shows around 20 processes with at most 1% memory usage. What's going on here? How can I find the culprit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading it wrong. You are actually only using 90MB of RAM, and Linux is using the rest for caches and buffers and such, that will be immediately freed once an application needs them.

Unused RAM is wasted RAM - so Linux uses it to speed up file accesses. This is a Good Thing (TM).

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, since processes actually fail with messages like `FATAL: fork() failed (reason: Cannot allocate memory)`. `top` also says: `Mem:   2097152k total,  2097152k used,        0k free,        0k buffers`.

Comment: @Nils: Nope, memory isn't your problem, you got plenty of that. Check out the second line in your original post, the one that shows memory usage minus the buffers - you have plenty of free memory. Try `ulimit -a` and see if your limits are the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that error message threw me off a bit.

How can I actually check how much of these limits I'm using right now?

Comment: @Nils: That I don't know. [These are the values I have on my machine](http://pastie.org/3776591) - if you have something very different from that, perhaps that's your problem.

Comment: @Nils: Also, check your system logs - The `dmesg` command and `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: I couldn't find any big difference between our ulimits, but anyway it looks like a restart fixed the problem for now. Thank you for your help!